# Change reply to employer on Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

After opening a message and hardly even reading it, I accidentally clicked the "Send Message" button. To my dismay, this has informed the employer that I am interested when it turns out I am not. Also to my dismay, there's no way to change my reply to "Not interested".

As a side note, my cursor changes to a pointer when I hover over the green bar that shows that I replied "interested", but clicking that bar doesn't actually do anything. It's just a CSS bug, but I feel teased because I wish I *could* interact with that green bar.

I suppose I should at least be glad I didn't accidentally reply "Not interested" to an employer I was actually interested in.

Comment: Reminds me of sending SMS to the wrong person. Happens to everyone, can't be changed either. ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS bug will be fixed soon. As far as the being able to change your reply, it's something we will consider, but there's a lot of other requests and projects that are a higher priority.

Comment: Juice, please consider changing/removing the status tag.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have a chance to change one's reply. Or, if I only have one chance to reply, perhaps a radio button shouldn't be checked by default? Or maybe I shouldn't be allowed to "Send message" when the message box is empty without confirming that I want to send an empty message.